# How to correctly use async-await with thread pool in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to achieve same effect as

```
# Code 1
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from time import sleep, time

def square(a):
    print('start', a)
    sleep(a)
    print('end', a)
    return a * a

def main():
    p = Pool(2)
    queue = list(range(4))
    start = time()
    results = p.map(square, queue)
    print(results)
    print(time() - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

with async functions like

```
# Code 2
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from time import sleep, time
import asyncio

async def square(a):
    print('start', a)
    sleep(a)  # await asyncio.sleep same effect
    print('end', a)
    return a * a

async def main():
    p = Pool(2)
    queue = list(range(4))
    start = time()
    results = p.map_async(square, queue)
    results = results.get()
    results = [await result for result in results]
    print(results)
    print(time() - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Currently Code 1 takes 4 seconds and Code 2 takes 6 seconds which means it is not running in parallel. What is the correct and cleanest way to run multiple async functions in parallel?

Better to be python 3.6 compatible. Thank you!

Comment: Try replacing `sleep` with `asyncio.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

`map_async()` is not the same "async" as in `async def` - if it is fed with an `async def` method, it won't actually run it but return a coroutine instance immediately (try calling such a method without `await`). Then you `await`ed on the 4 coroutines one by one, that equals to sequential execution, and ended up with 6 seconds.

Please see following example:

```
from time import time
import asyncio
from asyncio.locks import Semaphore

semaphore = Semaphore(2)


async def square(a):
    async with semaphore:
        print('start', a)
        await asyncio.sleep(a)
        print('end', a)
        return a * a


async def main():
    start = time()
    tasks = []
    for a in range(4):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(square(a)))
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print([t.result() for t in tasks])
    print(time() - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

The `Semaphore` acts similarly like the `ThreadPool` - it allows only 2 concurrent coroutines entering the `async with semaphore:` block.